# call of overloaded ‘max(char&, char&)’ is ambiguous

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int max (int a, int b) 
{ 
   return a<b?b:a; 
} 

template <typename T> T max (T a, T b) 
{ 
   return a<b?b:a; 
} 

template <typename T> T max (T a, T b, T c) 
{ 
   return max (max(a,b), c); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
   // The call with two chars work, flawlessly.
   :: max ('c', 'b');

   // This call with three chars produce the error listed below:
   :: max ('c', 'b', 'a');
   return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
error: call of overloaded ‘max(char&, char&)’ is ambiguous
```

Shouldn't this `max ('c', 'b', 'a')` call the overloaded function with three arguments?

Comment: Are you writing your own `max` function as a learning exercise? Why not just use std::max provided by the compiler?

Comment: @Victor That's just for playing around with templates.

Comment: That shows why it is important to read the entire error message. I'm sure it continues with a list of candidates and seeing std::max in there should have solved your problem.

Comment: Please: avoid `using namespace` declarations as much as possible, and for sure when you are reusing names present in the standard libraries!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thing is, there is already a `max` in `std`, and **you are saying `using namespace std;`**:

```
template <class T> const T& max ( const T& a, const T& b );
```

So your `max ('c', 'b', 'a')` is called fine; the problem is inside it.

```
template <typename T> T max (T a, T b, T c) 
{ 
   return max (max(a,b), c); /* Doesn't know which max to pick. */
}
```

I don't know why `max` is available since you didn't include `algorithm`, but apparently it is.

#### EDIT

If you want to keep that `using` at the top:

```
template <typename T> T max (T a, T b, T c) 
{ 
   return ::max(::max(a, b), c);
}
```

Comment: The OP is defining multiple max functions.  For this he does not need  to include the algorithm header.

Comment: @David and cnicutar: You said: `/* Doesn't know which max to pick. */` but can't it pick the template `max` with `two` arguments? After all, it is picking that when called with ` max ('c', 'b');`?
`

Comment: Yeah Got it now, thanks. But still, wondering, why it was working with the call `::max ('c', 'b')`, in main?

Comment: @Anisha Kaul Because `::` specifies "I want to use *my* `max`".

Comment: and BTW, writing simply @Anisha will do, no need to write the lengthy name. :)

Comment: @cnicutar A little nitpicking: Using :: does not say use mine, but rather use the one defined in the top level namespace. It might well be that in some header or other someone defines a max function in top level namespace. This should not happen in well-written and -encapsulated code, but you never know.

Answer (score 3):

There is NO ambiguous call. http://ideone.com/SJ5Jc (notice the second line is commented)

The problem is : `using namespace std` : http://ideone.com/T8tsv

It is causing problem, as it brings all symbols into the current namespace, and it seems `iostream` directly or indirecly includes the header which defines `std::max`. So when you write `::max` in your code, the compiler to unable to decide which `max` to choose : the one you've written or the one defined by the Standard library.

**Remove** `using namespace std;` from your code.

Comment: If there was no ambiguous call, I doubt the OP would have created the question. Their compiler certainly seems to think there is.

Comment: Because you didn't use `use namespace std` :-)

Comment: Thanks Nawaz, but then why it was working with ` max ('c', 'b')`?

Comment: @Anisha: You've not written `max('c','b')`. You've written `::max('c','b')`. There is a difference between the two. Second one is a qualified name which says : choose the one which is defined in the global namespace.

Comment: Oh yes, I have got it now. Actually `::max('c','b')` isn't just calling the three argumented function, its calling the function with two arguments.:)